# Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: /users", found none

Tags: angular, http, testing, jasmine

I have a very simple service call and a jasmine test for it.

Service call:

```
    getUserInfo() {
        return this.http.get('/users');
    }
```

Test method:

```
    it('should get user info', inject([UsersService, HttpTestingController], (service: UsersService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
        const testUser = [{username: 'testLogin', firstName: 'testFName', lastName: 'testLName'}];
        service.getUserInfo().subscribe( user => {
            expect(user).toEqual(testUser);
        });
        backend.expectOne({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/users'
        }).flush(testUser);
    }));
```

What i'm doing wrong? Why the karma is say error:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: /users", found none.

Comment: I am not sure, try to use this as a guide: https://medium.com/better-programming/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

import {
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      HttpTestingController
    } from "@angular/common/http/testing";

```
import { ApiService } from "./api.service";

describe("ApiService", () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let service: ApiService;
  const api_server="http://localhost:8080";

  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [],
      providers : [ApiService]
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(ApiService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it("should be created", () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should test getUserInfo()", () => {
    const testUser = [{username: 'testLogin', firstName: 'testFName', lastName: 'testLName'}];
    service.getUserInfo().subscribe(res => {
      expect(res).toEqual(testUser);
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(
      `${api_server}/users`
    );
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");
    req.flush(testUser);

    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```